# Doesn't work Welcome message to New User in Viber Bot 'conversation_started'

Tags: php, viber-api, viber-bot

I try to send a welcome message to a new unsigned user, but it doesn't work. Please, help how solve this problem? This code doesn't work:

```
elseif($input['event'] == 'conversation_started') {
//    "tracking_data" = "tracking data",
    $data['tracking_data'] = $tracking_data;
    $message['type'] = "text";
    $message['text'] = 'Text to new user';
    $message['keyboard'] = [
        "Type" => "keyboard",
        "DefaultHeight" => true,
        "Buttons" => [[
            "ActionType" => "reply",
            "ActionBody" => "main_menu",
            "Text" => "Main menu",
            "TextSize" => "regular"
        ]]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As viber documentation stated, user must be subscribed in order for bot to send any kind of message.

An approach to your problem is:

1. Create a JSON file to store **userProfiles**.
2. You should check inside **onConversationStarted()** if the userProfile is subscribed.
3. If yes, then use **bot.sendMessage()** to send your welcome message.

Please check how [Viber Documentation API](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/) works!